# HighChart with two axes and a pane

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i am using highchart to create a sample chart which will have two panes and also with two axes(one primary and other secondary axis).

For reference i found this [high chart candlestick and pane](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/er65cghm/3/) .For setting up  multiple axes i have done something like this...

```
  //yAxis: chartYAxis,
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: 'Temp'
    },
    min:40,
    lineWidth: 2,
    opposite: true
}
, {
    title: {
        text: 'Status'
    },
    top: '65%',
    height: '35%',
    offset: 1,
    lineWidth: 2
}],
```

Here is the output that i want to have with primary axis haiving KW and secondary axis with temperature.

[image]

If anyone knows how to get around this,please help! Any idea and pointer will be much appreciated!!

Comment: the yAxis array that you added in the answer, is the same as in the stock higchart demo, could you create a fiddle to reproduce the problem, or at least give us a sample of the data you are using?

Comment: @Liviu Boboia, Just added a fiddle.

Comment: you just need to set the axis that you want to the left to opposite:false, the default being true, here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/er65cghm/4/

Comment: I have updated the image please have a look..

Comment: @LiviuBoboia, am i doing something forgetting something? Please help

Comment: take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/, you also need to give the serie the axis it should belong to, ie  yAxis: 2

Comment: I got your point but how to add a pane with some content here.

Comment: You were right setting the axis just solved my problem. Just had set the height of the y-axis properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate !!!